# How to drop single aspects of a variable in a glm?

Tags: r, regression, glm

I am currently analyzing the occupancy of bat boxes and the factors that are influencing the occupancy. To determine the most significant factors I am running a glm. My response variable is binary data (0=occupied / 1=not occupied) and my explanatory variables are numerical execpt one categorial variable with 4 levels Bat box mounted on tree/pole/balcony/facade).

So I fitted all my factors in the glm:

```
modelb <- glm(occupation ~ TreeCov500 + distance + Water2000 + greenvol + height + age + shadow + exposition + number_of_boxes + mounted_on)
```

the summary yields (cant embend picture due to low reputation):

Factor  p-value

(Intercept)             0.2704
TreeCov500              0.2859
distance             0.3412
Water2000              0.3165
greenvol             0.2194
height            0.2305
age                   0.3940
shadow              0.2939
exposition              0.6039
number_of_boxes          0.0154
mounted_onTREES       0.7676
mounted_onFACADES   0.4319
mounted_onPOLES    0.0770

My problem: I want to drop the variable with the highest p-value. mounted_onTREES has the highest p-value. How can I drop this single aspect? I do not want to drop the the whole variable mounted_on (because mounted_onPOLES has a very low p-value).

I tried:

```
modelc<-update(modelb,~. -mounted_onTREES)
```

But that did not worked. So does even make sence to drop single aspects of one variable? If not how should I handle the variable mounted_on? Should I keep it as long as one of the aspects has a very low p-value?

I am very thankfull for every help!

Comment: Why do you want to drop one of the category (`TREES`) in the variable `mounted_on`? I think this is the result you want to see. It means `TREES`, compared to the baseline, does not show a significantly mean value. This is a meaningful result.

Comment: You are right. I found a similar answer in an other forum. So I have to keep all dummie variables. But another questions pops up now: I want to remove as much non significant varibles as possible until I have reached the lowest AIC possible. My three dummie variables have different p-values. When I compare the different p-values of my variables, do I use the lowest p-value of the three dummie variables for the comparism with the other variables (like height, etc.)? (I hope the question is clear enough)

Comment: I feel like for dummy variables, using the lowest P value is fine.